# how to translate Sum product formula in power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have this data table, where i want to calculate the final score based on CI value my excel formula is =SUMPRODUCT(--(H4:H20>0),H4:H20,E4:E20)/SUMIF(H4:H20,">0",E4:E20)

[image]

Comment: Please put the excel column names (H, E) at least.

Comment: Your formula references go from row 4 to row 20 - 17 rows, but your screenshot is showing 19 rows of data.  Your final score is correct if you miss the first two rows of data.  Is that by design?

Comment: I don't think the `(H4:H20>0)` part is necessary in the SUMPRODUCT.  As it multiplies one column by the other any with 0 in a column will return 0 anyway.

Comment: i removed some of the columns to clean the sheet. below is current formula =SUMPRODUCT(--(H2:H18>0),H2:H18,E2:E18)/SUMIF(H2:H18,">0",E2:E18)

Comment: The `Infra_l3_wght` column isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this:

```
Your_Measure =
ROUND (
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX ( SumProduct, IF ( SumProduct[score] > 0, [score] * [CI] ) ),
        SUMX ( SumProduct, IF ( [score] > 0, [CI] ) )
    ),
    6
)
```

Result It produces :

[image: HGHGGH]

Comment: Table Name... Put the name of your table in its place, and run the code:

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are looking for is

```
final score = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(
        'Table',
        'Table'[CI] * 'Table'[score]
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[CI]),
        'Table'[score] > 0
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks works like a magic, i was missing that calculate bit